# echo command in script wiht input from excel.txt file

Tags: excel, echo

First: Many thanks for taking the effort to read and answer this post

**What I want to do:**

I would like to read lines from a txt file (each line may contain 1 or 2 words) and then echo a text saying:

curl "text.word1+word2"

**How I do it**:

```
while read line
   do
      kw=( $line )
      echo 'curl "text.'${kw[0]}+${kw[1]}'"'
   done
```

Remark: there are additional if command in my file i did not post here

**Problem**

While this works fine when I execute it in the terminal and enter a line in the terminal, it does not product the desired result when I use a txt file as input

The text file is an excel file where I have text in the first column. I save the excel file as "Windows formatted text (.txt) and can open the resulting name.txt file in an editor (seeing a "normal" text file)

when I use in the terminal now

```
./myscript.command < name.txt
```

the result will be

**"url "text.word1+word2** 
instead of 
**curl "text.word1+word2"**

Any ideas how to solve this?

Many thanks!

Comment: "Many thanks for taking the effort to read and answer this post" - what if *no-one* answers? :-)

Comment: I guess in that case I would have to edit my post and delete the many thanks (and be really angry)   :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`${kw[1]}` has a carriage return character at the end of it, what you're seeing is:

```
curl "text.word1+word2
"
```

with the second line overwriting the first.

You can confirm this by doing a hex dump on the file, such as with:

```
od -xcb name.txt
```

and looking for those pesky `\r` characters.

The following transcript shows this in detail:

```
pax> od -xcb name.txt
0000000    6150    2078    6944    6261    6f6c    0a0d
          P   a   x       D   i   a   b   l   o  \r  \n
        120 141 170 040 104 151 141 142 154 157 015 012
0000014

pax> cat name.sh
#!/bin/bash
while read line ; do
    kw=( $line )
    echo 'curl "text.'${kw[0]}+${kw[1]}'"'
done <name.txt

pax> ./name.sh
"url "text.Pax+Diablo
```

As to how you get rid of the carriage return, there are numerous solutions, some of which are:

- `dos2unix`;
- `tr -d '\r'`; or
- `sed 's/\r$//'`.

Your weapon of choice depends on what tools you have available to you, `dos2unix` is probably the easiest if you have it to hand.

Comment: you safed my day ! Unfortunately mac does not provide dos2unix. I searched in the forum and found that 

perl -pe 's/\r\n|\n|\r/\n/g' inputfile > outputfile

resolved my issues. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

DOS uses CRLF for new line(each line ends with two characters, CR then LF). Unix uses LF only (each line ends with an \n character).

To convert dos file format into unix file format use

```
$ dos2unix filename
```

It will solve your problem.

Comment: you safed my day ! Unfortunately mac does not provide dos2unix. I searched in the forum and found that 

perl -pe 's/\r\n|\n|\r/\n/g' inputfile > outputfile

resolved my issues. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine:

```
while read line
do
        kw=( $line )
        echo 'curl "text.'${kw[0]}+${kw[1]}'"'
done < $1
```

And generates:

```
./text_line.sh text.txt 
curl "text.aaa+aaa"
curl "text.bbb+bbb"
curl "text.ccc+"
curl "text.ddd+ddd"
```